# Bootstrap - Flex Box Container With Scrollable Content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I am trying to build a fairly standard application layout with Bootstrap 5 and flexbox, consisting of a top bar, bottom bar and an auto-sized content area. The content area is split into a side bar and a main content area.

For reference I want it to look something like VSCode.

[image]

With some tags omitted for brevity, here is what I have so far:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="h-100 mh-100" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        .sidebar {
            background: red;
            flex: 0 0 25%;
        }

        .main {
            background: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="h-100 mh-100">
    <div class="h-100 mh-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="bg-dark text-white p-1">
            <span>Top Bar</span>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-fill d-flex flex-row">
            <aside class="sidebar d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="bg-dark text-white p-1">
                    <span>Side Title Bar</span>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-content overflow-scroll">
                    <div style="height: 0; background: magenta;"></div>
                </div>
            </aside>
            <main class="main flex-fill">
            </main>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-primary text-white p-1">
            <span>Bottom Bar</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

What I want is for the sidebar content to scroll when it exceeds the available space in the viewport, but for example if you increase the height of the content `div` in the sidebar the whole lot scrolls together, and pushes the bottom bar out of view.

How do I keep all panels in view (top, bottom, side and main), and allow individual panels to scroll when necessary, without pushing the content out of view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the **flex-*** and **overflow-*** classes. Also, it's easier to set the height using `vh-100` so that you don't need to set `h-100` on html, body, container, etc...

```
<div class="vh-100 d-flex flex-column overflow-hidden">
    <div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-dark text-white p-1">
        <span>Top Bar</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-fill d-flex flex-row overflow-auto">
        <aside class="sidebar d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="bg-dark text-white p-1">
                <span>Side Title Bar</span>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar-content p-2 overflow-auto">
                
            </div>
        </aside>
        <main class="main flex-fill p-3 overflow-auto">
            
        </main>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-primary text-white p-1">
        <span>Bottom Bar</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/gnjF44KRcV)

---

Related: [How to implement responsive, independently scrolling panes in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752637/)